# What's in the QstringList returned by QCoreApplication::arguments()?

Tags: macos, command-line, qcoreapplication

feel free to edit my question if this explanation seems not relevant to it.

As it is written in my question, I'd like to know what is returned by the function arguments() of the QCoreApplication. In fact, I know that the first argument (.at(0)) will be the name of my application. My problem is, when I tried to open a file by double-clicking it, I thought that i could get the file name with QCoreApplication::arguments().at(1)  but it doesn't seem to be the case : the length of the list returned is still 1, and it is (of course) my application name. As a consequence, my application starts but without opening the file... And I don't know where to retrieve the name when I double-click it.

Basically, my question is to know what the double-click is doing on OSX, in reference to the command line.

Note : it happens only when I try to open a file by double clicking it or doing right-click->open with. When I open a file if the application is running, it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#arguments)?  Seems pretty clear.

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah, and argv[] still has only 1 argument. I just want to know where the name of the file opened with double-click goes because I can't retrieve it with argv[].

Comment: It's at index `0` as expected.  Are you getting array lengths and array indexes mixed-up, perhaps?  If an array has length 1 then only index 0 is available.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think you misunderstood what I said. My array length is always 1, and the first argument (at index `0` of course ;) ) is always the name of my application (not the name of my file)

Comment: OK.  So the thing you are double-clicking is a file that's associated with your application?  If that's the case then I would expect 2 arguments in the array.

Comment: That's it, but I don't have two arguments, only one... Hence my question